# Pre-loading site layer and Jquery

Tags: jquery, preload

Anyone can tell me WHAT is wrong with this code. Doesn´t work for me. I put big images (size) to test, but still not working.

Pre loading site with DIV, image pre-loading and JQUERY

On the

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    10000000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) 
                url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif') 
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}


body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}


body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
$body = $("body");

$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");   },
     ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading");  }    
});


</script>
```

**And before**

```
<div class="modal"><!-- Place at bottom of page --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: if that code is in head....you are looking for `$('body')` before it exists. `Doesn´t work for me` is not a proper problem description, especially when you haven't defined what you expect the code to do or what it is doing. It is basically meaningless

Comment: It´s a preloader. So... The idea is to charge a layer (div) during the body or all elements of the web are loading.

Comment: and that should be explained in the question along with proper problem description

Comment: I thought It was pretty clear. Sorry! My mistake :D And thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe to some....maybe not all. Also consider these questions are here long term for others who may have similar issues. Assumptions are dangerous and all I'm doing is nudging you towards some guidelines outlined in help center such as : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: im not too sure about jquery on...but ajaxstart is not a js event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events so is it meant to be used as a method `$(document).ajaxstart();`?

Comment: Really good tip! I did not consider it! Thanks and... It will be a good point for the future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate your code inside:

```
$(function () {
    $body = $("body");

    $(document).on({
        ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");   },
         ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading");  }    
    });
});
```

To execute after the page is loaded. If you don't want your contents to be shown by start, then add a class like `loading`, even before you load the contents:

```
<body class="loading">
```

Comment: I updated the JS script. But it´s still not working. The elements charge but the modal or DIV does not appear covering all the site during all the elements (images, and all the page) load.